# Svg scale path at a center point (pulsating)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to `animate` several `paths` in an `svg` around two `circles`. My goal is to `scale` the `paths` at center, as if they were pulsating. I've looked at every answer on stackoverflow to figure out how to achieve this. [The closest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19742574/6275623) I have found did not wok.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mc2964vn/) of what I have so far. As you can see, the `paths` are scaling away/towards the origin. If there is no way to achieve this with `CSS`, is it possible to achieve this with a `javascript` framework like `Velocity.js`?

This is the SVG:

```
      <div class="wrapper">
          <svg version="1.1" viewBox="20 20 60 60" >
          <g class="icon-sun">
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M64.175,38.688c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828l2.828-2.828c0.779-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.828,0c0.779,0.781,0.779,2.047,0,2.828L64.175,38.688z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M64.175,38.688c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828l2.828-2.828c0.779-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.828,0c0.779,0.781,0.779,2.047,0,2.828L64.175,38.688z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M50.034,34.002c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-2v-3.999c0-1.104,0.895-2,2-2c1.104,0,2,0.896,2,2v3.999C52.034,33.106,51.136,34.002,50.034,34.002z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M35.893,38.688l-2.827-2.828c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828c0.78-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.827,0l2.827,2.828c0.781,0.781,0.781,2.047,0,2.828C37.94,39.469,36.674,39.469,35.893,38.688z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M34.034,50c0,1.104-0.896,1.999-2,1.999h-4c-1.104,0-1.998-0.896-1.998-1.999s0.896-2,1.998-2h4C33.14,48,34.034,48.896,34.034,50z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M35.893,61.312c0.781-0.78,2.048-0.78,2.827,0c0.781,0.78,0.781,2.047,0,2.828l-2.827,2.827c-0.78,0.781-2.047,0.781-2.827,0c-0.781-0.78-0.781-2.047,0-2.827L35.893,61.312z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M50.034,65.998c1.104,0,2,0.895,2,1.999v4c0,1.104-0.896,2-2,2c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-2v-4C48.034,66.893,48.929,65.998,50.034,65.998z"/>
              <path class="icon-sun-beam"
                    d="M64.175,61.312l2.828,2.828c0.779,0.78,0.779,2.047,0,2.827c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0l-2.828-2.827c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.048,0-2.828C62.126,60.531,63.392,60.531,64.175,61.312z"/>
              <circle class="icon-sun-outline"
                      cx="50.034"
                      cy="50"
                      r="11.999"/>
              <circle class="icon-sun-fill"
                      fill="#FFFFFF"
                      cx="50.034"
                      cy="50"
                      r="7.999"/>
            </g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-sun-beam {
  animation-name: scale;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-direction: alternate;

}

.icon-sun-beam:nth-child(even) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s, 4.5s;
}

.icon-sun {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 18s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}

svg {
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.85, 0.85);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.35, 1.35);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you mean, and what you need help with. I don't see how this is a minimal example showing your problem.

Comment: @Persijn In the jsfiddle demo, you can see that the shapes defined in the paths are scaling in size as they rotate around the circle. As the paths scale, they also move away/closer to the circle on the x/y axis. I am trying to make the paths scale without moving away/closer to the circle.

Comment: @IgnatOspadov change the origin for the rays to `transform-origin: 50%;` and not `50px`. Although in some browsers `%` uses the scale of the whole canvas. [Bug 1209061](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061)

Comment: @Erevald this works but it only in Chrome. Is there a cross-browser solution?

Comment: @IgnatOspadov give [mo.js](http://mojs.io/) a look.

Comment: @Erevald thanks. Ill try it out. Have you happened to also use GreenSock/GSAP?

Comment: @IgnatOspadov, yes Ive used the tweening library from GSAP, its great. Altho for this example you could use the svg paths as icon font too and it would work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution, that is cross-browser.

Just give each of your sunbeams its own absolute `transform-origin`.

```css
    .wrapper {
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .icon-sun-beam {
      animation-name: scale;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      
    }
    
    .icon-sun-beam:nth-child(even) {
      animation-delay: 4.5s, 4.5s;
    }
    
    .icon-sun {
      animation-name: rotate;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-duration: 18s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      transform-origin: 50px 50px;
    }
    
    svg {
      shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes scale {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.85, 0.85);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1.35, 1.35);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
              <svg version="1.1" viewBox="20 20 60 60" >
              <g class="icon-sun">
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 70.0px 50.0px;"
                        d="M72.03,51.999 
                        h-3.998 
                        c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-1.999 
                        s0.895-2,2-2h3.998
                        c1.104,0,2,0.896,2,2
                        S73.136,51.999,72.03,51.999z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 64.2px 35.9px;"
                        d="M64.175,38.688c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828l2.828-2.828c0.779-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.828,0c0.779,0.781,0.779,2.047,0,2.828L64.175,38.688z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 50.0px 30.0px;"
                        d="M50.034,34.002c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-2v-3.999c0-1.104,0.895-2,2-2c1.104,0,2,0.896,2,2v3.999C52.034,33.106,51.136,34.002,50.034,34.002z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 35.9px 35.9px;"
                        d="M35.893,38.688l-2.827-2.828c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047,0-2.828c0.78-0.781,2.047-0.781,2.827,0l2.827,2.828c0.781,0.781,0.781,2.047,0,2.828C37.94,39.469,36.674,39.469,35.893,38.688z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 30.0px 50.0px;"
                        d="M34.034,50c0,1.104-0.896,1.999-2,1.999h-4c-1.104,0-1.998-0.896-1.998-1.999s0.896-2,1.998-2h4C33.14,48,34.034,48.896,34.034,50z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 35.9px 64.1px;"
                        d="M35.893,61.312c0.781-0.78,2.048-0.78,2.827,0c0.781,0.78,0.781,2.047,0,2.828l-2.827,2.827c-0.78,0.781-2.047,0.781-2.827,0c-0.781-0.78-0.781-2.047,0-2.827L35.893,61.312z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 50.0px 70.0px;"
                        d="M50.034,65.998c1.104,0,2,0.895,2,1.999v4c0,1.104-0.896,2-2,2c-1.105,0-2-0.896-2-2v-4C48.034,66.893,48.929,65.998,50.034,65.998z"/>
                  <path class="icon-sun-beam" style="transform-origin: 64.2px 64.1px;"
                        d="M64.175,61.312l2.828,2.828c0.779,0.78,0.779,2.047,0,2.827c-0.781,0.781-2.049,0.781-2.828,0l-2.828-2.827c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.048,0-2.828C62.126,60.531,63.392,60.531,64.175,61.312z"/>
                  <circle class="icon-sun-outline"
                          cx="50.034"
                          cy="50"
                          r="11.999"/>
                  <circle class="icon-sun-fill"
                          fill="#FFFFFF"
                          cx="50.034"
                          cy="50"
                          r="7.999"/>
                </g>
          </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [GSAP](https://greensock.com) library to animate the SVG. I chose to do this because there was no solution that would have worked without breaking the animation on either Chrome or Firefox. This is the code that I have tested which works on IE 11, Firefox and Chrome. I used `Jquery` and `TweenMax` libraries.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sun = $(".icon-sun");
    var sunBeamEven = $(".icon-sun-beam:even");
    var sunBeamOdd = $(".icon-sun-beam:odd");
    function animateSun(){
    TweenMax.to(sun, 12, {rotation:"+=360", svgOrigin:"50 50", smoothOrigin:true, repeat:-1, ease:Linear.easeNone});
    TweenMax.to(sunBeamEven, 4, {scale:0.5, transformOrigin:"50% 50%", repeat:-1, yoyo:true, ease:Linear.easeNone});
    TweenMax.to(sunBeamOdd, 4, {scale:0.5, transformOrigin:"50% 50%", repeat:-1, yoyo:true, ease:Linear.easeNone, delay:3});
  }
animateSun();
```