# How to scale and center an svg path not at the origin

Tags: javascript, svg

I have two paths, one of which is scaled (see fiddle).  The scaling also results in a translation for reasons outlined here: [SVG - scale path from center repetitively (pulsating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742574/svg-scale-path-from-center-repetitively-pulsating) .  I need them centered on each other.

https://jsfiddle.net/bjxvda1w/1/

```html
<svg width="400" height="210">
    <g transform='translate(0 200)'>
        <path d="M 53.3, -96 L37.3 -96 L37.3 -160 L69.3 -160 L69.3 -96 L53.3 -96 Z" fill="red" ></path>
        <path d="M 53.3, -96 L37.3 -96 L37.3 -160 L69.3 -160 L69.3 -96 L53.3 -96 Z" fill="green" opacity=".6" transform="scale(1.3)"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, the path is generated by another tool so I am not able to create the path at the origin, scale it and translate it as per the accepted answer.  If anyone could help with some code that would calculate appropriate x/y translate values for a x/y scale to keep the shapes centered I'd be grateful!

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671100/scale-path-from-center#11671373